# ASP Is a foreach loop based on Button control on a Master page possible?

Tags: asp.net, button, foreach

I'm trying to dynamically turn off all buttons on a webpage for a practicular group of users.  So what I want to do is just set visble and enable = false.

So i'm kind of looking for something like this below.

```
foreach(Button idvButton on Master)
{
 idvButton.Visible = false;
 idvButton.Enable = false;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this from your child page's code behind?

```
foreach(var btn in Master.Page.Form.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
   btn.Visible = false;
   btn.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: I got the error:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Wasim just because its not visible does not mean u can't temper data or fiddlers

Comment: @p.campbell nope same error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @p.campbell  here is the answer had to use this.Page

Comment: You didn't specify where you were calling this from. My answer specified "from your child page". Easy to convert to the Master's POV by using `this`, as you found.

Comment: @WasimAlatrash What does this have to do with anything? This question is about finding controls of a certain type.

Answer (score 1):

This disables all buttons found throughout entire MasterPage.

```
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
        {
            disableButtons(ctrl);
        }
    }

    void disableButtons(Control ctrl)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl2 in ctrl.Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl2.GetType() == typeof(Button))
            {
                ((Button)ctrl2).Enabled = false;
                ((Button)ctrl2).Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:  Had to combine both previous posts.

```
                foreach (var btn in this.Page.Form.Controls.OfType<RadButton>())
                {
                    btn.Visible = false;
                    btn.Enabled = false;
                }
```